# No named parameters of function are inserted into subfunctions with different parameter name automaticaly

Tags: javascript

i hope the title is well chosen.So im learning JavaScript from tutorial on this site https://javascript.info/ ,i have problem with task 1 from chapter decorators apply/call

I have been searching here on stack overflow and internet and i couldnt find the answer

```
function work(a, b) {
    alert( a + b ); // work is an arbitrary function or method
}

function spy(func) {
    function wrapper(...args) {
         wrapper.calls.push(args);
         return func.apply(this,arguments);
    }
    wrapper.calls = []
    return wrapper;
}
work = spy(work)
work(1, 2); // 3
work(4, 5); // 9
```

At the code there is a function work with arguments a and b, these arguments can be copied to local variables and functions, here these arguments are copied in function spy to the subfunction wrapper, my problem is why a and b is copied into ...args with word args, which are converted by rest operator ... into an array [a,b] . I can use any word like hello, cow ( for the whole code) and the result is still same, so how does the javascript know that call with word args wants a and b

PS. When copying arguments into local variables i would use it like :    let value = a; 
so i will call it by the name of the parameter not by a different name(if im not mistaken)

Comment: `...args` is an example of *argument destructuring*, described in section 6.2 of that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript only does positional arguments. The names are just for clarity. ...args strips them away.

The call to the "func" function in your code above passes the arguments in the same order as they are received but loses the name.